# C# Playing sound before closing form

Tags: c#, audio, formclosing

I try to play a sound before closing my program. I set that sound for my Exit Button. Here is my code (I used the library **WMPLib**):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        WindowsMediaPlayer btnPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        btnPlayer.URL = "Wrong.wav";
        btnPlayer.controls.play();
        //Thread.Sleep(2000); 
        this.Close();
}
```

My problem is: It exits immediately and doesn't play the sound. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Use `thread` or `async method` to play sound. When method ends work and then close form

Comment: Try adding a timer with like a second then close the form

Comment: why this line is commented out: Thread.Sleep(2000);

Comment: @AminurRashid Because I think it will wait and play sound completely

Comment: @HoangViet, I think that will delay the app closing and thus let the music play

Comment: @AminurRashid I tried but It just wait 2 seconds and then close the form without play the sound

Comment: you can increase the delay time. Thread.Sleep(2000), here 2000 is in miliseconds which results 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `WindowsMediaPlayer.Play` returns immediately.

You should subscribe for the state change event like this:

```
btnPlayer.PlayStateChange += this.PlayStateChange;
```

And there:

```
private void PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

It's all [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)